# How to Vim Search with wildcard chars

Tags: vim

so I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible or not. I have a huge file, each line of the file has some record in it and there are some 20k lines. Few of the lines have some variables wrapped in double underscores like this:

```
abc def __var1__.
```

Only a few lines would have multiple variables in the same line. Something like:

```
abc def __var1__ ghi jkl __var2__. zyx...
```

Now, I am wondering if I could search for those lines. I tried this search pattern:

```
/__*__*__*__ (didn't work)
/__**__      (this also didn't work)
```

Could you please help me here. I am sure there would be some sort of wildcard character to do this.

Comment: `/__\w\+__.*__\w\+__` ?

Comment: @yolenoyer what would be better? `\w` or `.`? I used `.` so that even if the string has non-word character, it would be captured.

Comment: Yes of course you can use `.`. My pattern supposes that the variable names will only contain alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way around(not sure if that's the best way though):

```
/".\+__.\+__.\+__.\+__.
```

Here is the explaination:

```
" => My Line starts with double quote
.\+__ => Any Char until "__"
```

And this way I check if the line has more than or equal to 3 "__".